# Radio button losing tab index when styling

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have a radio button with two inputs. I am styling the radio button using css. Since i am applying `display:none` to the radio button it is losing its tab index( not able to toggle between the input using keyboard ). What is the alternate method ?

```
            <div class="col-md-12 cargo-shape">
                <span>
                    <div class="radio-btn image-radio text-uppercase">
                        <label>
                            <input formControlName="cargo_shape" type="radio" [value]="cargoShapes.package">
                            <span></span> <!-- radio button styling -->                                
                            <div class="label-text">{{ 'SPRINT3.PACKAGE' | translate }}</div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </span>
                <span class="mx-4">
                    <div class="radio-btn image-radio text-uppercase">
                        <label>
                            <input formControlName="cargo_shape" type="radio" [value]="cargoShapes.container">
                            <span> </span>
                            <!-- radio button styling -->
                            <div class="label-text"> {{ 'SPRINT3.CONTAINER' | translate }}</div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
```

i am styling the span tag and applying `display none` to input.

Comment: Give it a position left: -9999

Comment: add tab-index="1"

Comment: try `opacity: 0.001` instead, it may preserve tab indexes

Comment: Isn't this actually bootstrap? You need to tag it as such if it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `display: none` to `opacity: 0` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two things:

- Add `tab-index="1"` to  tags to make it navigatable by keyboard.
- Add `span:focus` styles.

The focus styles are applied by browser by default on input elements.

[An example with your code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzbKrM) :)

More info:

[Focus selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) 
[HTML tabindex Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Change `display: none` to `opacity: 0` and `position: absolute` to remove it from the document flow. (Use the arrows to change the selected radio button)